# What is this string for a SVG icon and how do I get it?

Tags: svg, shopify, polaris

I am using this NPM package @eastsideco/polaris-vue from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@eastsideco/polaris-vue). Its basically a way to use Shopify's Polaris framework but instead of React you can use Vue.js. Which is what I want.

One issue I'm having is the Shopify Icons. Here in the example page they are using this long string of characters instead of the SVG icon. See this:

```
icon: '&lt;svg class=&quot;Polaris-Icon__Svg&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 20 20&quot;&gt;&lt;path d=&quot;M13.707 10.707a.997.997 0 0 1-1.414 0L11 9.414V17a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V9.414l-1.293 1.293a.999.999 0 1 1-1.414-1.414l3-3a.999.999 0 0 1 1.414 0l3 3a.999.999 0 0 1 0 1.414zM17 2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v11a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-3a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h2V4H4v9h2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14z&quot; fill-rule=&quot;evenodd&quot;&gt;&lt;/path&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;'
```

And that totally works! I was able to also use it in my pages. I have no clue what that string is or where it comes from. So my question is how can I get that for other icons? [For example this cart Icon from the Shopify Icon explorer page.](https://polaris-icons.shopify.com/?icon=CartMajor)

I open the web console and see something but its not the same as above. How in the world can I translate the icons I see to the string above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a random string but a regular svg. All special characters like `<>"` are replaced with HTML entities.

> An HTML entity is a piece of text ("string") that begins with an ampersand (`&`) and ends with a semicolon (`;`) . Entities are frequently used to display reserved characters (which would otherwise be interpreted as HTML code), and invisible characters (like non-breaking spaces). You can also use them in place of other characters that are difficult to type with a standard keyboard.
>   Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Here is a list of the entities in provided svg:

- `&lt;` = `<`
- `&quot;` = `"`
- `&gt;`= `>`

To replace it in any svg just use "find and replace" in your code editor, it's the easiest way.

In case you need more entities here is full list: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: ok that's making more sense.. it also looks like there is ASCII encoding as well in there. Now its making more sense.. thanks for the heads up!